# Link between docker container and Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

Is is possible to link a docker container with a service running in minikube? I have a mysql container which I want to access using PMA pod in minikube. I have tried adding PMA_HOST is the yaml file while creating pod but getting an error on the PMA GUI page mentioning -

**mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused**

Comment: Verifying: I think you're saying: I'm running PhPMyAdmin in MiniKube.  I want to connect to a MySQL instance that I also have running in MiniKube.  How can I point my PhPMyAdmin instance to the MySQL instance?  (Note that I don't have such an environment readily available to help you answer your question - just trying to help you clarify your question.)

Comment: Provide mysql dockerfile, docker-compose or docker run used. Is this mysql accessible from outside? Also provide you pma pod yaml

Comment: @TinaC PhPMyAdmin is running in MiniKube, MySQL is running as a docker container which is not a part of MiniKube.

Comment: @Narain - Docker run command - docker run -td --name mysql -p 6033:3306/tcp <imageID>

Comment: PMA yaml -
`---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: phpmyadmin
  name: phpmyadmin
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: phpmyadmin
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin
  labels:
    name: phpmyadmin
spec:
  containers:
    - name: phpmyadmin
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      env:
       - name: PMA_HOST
         value: mysql
       - name: PMA_PORT
         value: “6033”
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: phpmyadmin
`

Comment: @KshitijKumar have you considered using mysql as another pod in the minikube? It would simplify the process and goal which you want to achieve - not only from the architecture side but also networking and volume consuming.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to access a service (mysql) running outside kube cluster (minikube) from that kube cluster.

You have two ways to achieve this:

1. make sure your networking is configured in a way allowinf traffic passing both ways correctly. Then you should be able to access that mysql service directly by it's address or by creating external service inside kube cluster (create `Service` with no selector and manualy configure external `Endpoint`s
2. Use something like ie. telepresence.io to expose localy developed service inside remote kubernetes cluster

Comment: Could you explain more on manually configuring Endpoints or provide some document link?

Comment: You can find information about endpoints in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)